# Ajax success callback unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a `href` link for my `unordered` list.

When the page loads for the first time, only the welcome page is visible as expected.

When I click on the list for the first time after the page loads, I get the desired results on the desired div after clicking on the href link on the ul li.

However, if I subsequently click on the other tab, the results are displayed on the one I had clicked before. For example, if i click on href #tab2a, the results will be displayed on #tab2b and vice versa. AJAX will direct results to the div I clicked on previously.

I'm at a loss here! How can I force the results to be displayed in the div that's referenced by the href id tag? I'm using an if else if condition; is this the right approach?

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#tab2").hide();
      $("#tab3").hide();
      $("#tab6").hide();
      $("#tab2a").hide();
      $("#tab2b").hide();
      $('ul li a').click(function() {
        href = undefined;
        if (($(this).attr('href')) == "#tab2a") {
          var href = $(this).attr('href');
          $.ajax({
            url: "http://mypage1_action=execute"
          }).done(function(data) {
            $(href).html(data);
          });
          $(href).show();
          $('form#tab div:not(' + href + ')').hide();
        } else if (($(this).attr('href')) == "#tab2b") {
          var href = $(this).attr('href');
          $.ajax({
            url: "http://mypage1_action=execute"
          }).done(function(data) {
            $(href).html(data);
          });
          $(href).show();
          $('form#tab div:not(' + href + ')').hide();
        } else {
          $(href).show();
          $('form#tab div:not(' + href + ')').hide();
        };
      });
```

HTML

```
<form id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='#tab1'><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#tab2'><span>Tab2</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#tab2a'><span>Tab 2a</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#tab2b'><span>Tab 2b</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#tab2c'><span>Tab 2c</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#tab3'><span>Tab 3</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Tab 3a</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Tab 3b</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Tab 3c</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#tab4'><span>Tab 4</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#tab5'><span>Contact</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='last'><a href='#tab6'><span>Contact</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>

<form id="tab" class=".allclass">
  <div id="tab1" class='active'>
    <h1>Welcome Page</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2">
  </div>
  <div id="tab2a">
  </div>
  <div id="tab2b">
  </div>
  <div id="tab3">
  </div>
  <div id="tab6">
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kBoni/1ag0ymh/#&togetherjs=m9pPoV3yoy

Comment: I'm trying to upload my current html

Comment: Updated. My apologies. wifi interuption

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused because by the time the `.done()` executes, the value of the `href` variable may have changed because you've clicked another tab, a simple way to avoid that is to wrap the `ajax()` code into a new function, and pass the `href` value as a parameter

```
function changeTab(href) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://mypage1_action=execute"
  }).done(function(data) {
    $(href).html(data);
  });
  $(href).show();
  $('form#tab div:not(' + href + ')').hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tab2,#tab3,#tab6,#tab2a,#tab2b").hide();
  $('ul li a').click(function() {
    href = undefined;
    if (($(this).attr('href')) == "#tab2a") {
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      changeTab(href);
    } else if (($(this).attr('href')) == "#tab2b") {
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      changeTab(href);
    } else {
      $(href).show();
      $('form#tab div:not(' + href + ')').hide();
    };
  });
});
```

Now, if you also want to have a different `url` for every tab, (which you probably do), you can add it as a `data-attribute` to your `a` and pass it to the function:

```
function changeTab(href,url) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url
  }).done(function(data) {
    $(href).html(data);
  });
  $(href).show();
  $('form#tab div:not(' + href + ')').hide();
}
.
.
.
if (($(this).attr('href')) == "#tab2a") {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
  changeTab(href,url);
}
```